# Why exactly is it bad practice to position elements with <br>?

Tags: html

I have been told using `br` elements is a very bad idea, but how would **you** explain to a "newbie" why it's bad practice?

Here's an example --

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href='/'>Click Here</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p> For any inquiries call (999) 999 9999 </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice because you cannot change and control your layout with css. For example when you want to do a flexbox or a fluent layout you still have this linebreaks in place. Do the line brakes with css using:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Was just wondering how to properly word this. Thanks!