# CSS - Why are there so many ways to position, and which is the right way?

Tags: html, css

This is slightly a philosophical and not 100%-hard code-oriented question, but it has to do with programming standards and I hope it fits the rules.

While learning web development, I have always been intrigued by positioning. My first noob websites looked like this:

```
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to my website. </h1>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br>
    <p> Copyright 2016 </p>
</body>
```

However I always felt uneasy doing this - after all, this tag was almost never used in any professional websites I saw, and after asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836393/why-exactly-is-it-bad-practice-to-position-elements-with-br) I understood it did not allow for any additional markup and was not semantic.

I looked for other ways, and then stumbled upon `position: absolute`. I basically used this by setting manual position for *every element on my page* because I did not know any other way to use `position: absolute` and not do it that way. **The websites looked fine on my screen but the slightest resize ruined them.**

Looking for another solution, I just thought of positioning everything with `margin`. For example, instead of `<br><br>` I would do `margin-top: 5%`. I still do this right now and it feels very wrong.

So I was just looking for general advice -- how does the majority do it? What is best practice? There are apparently hundreds of ways to do it and I've looked through many guides and tutorials but I just don't get CSS positioning.

Comment: I would steer clear of using absolute positioning for the general layout of a page, as you've said 'the slightest resize ruins them'. The general rule of thumb I tend to follow is build from the top down using margin-bottom to position the following elements, that combined with floats and clears is the best way I find to work, however like everything, it depends very much on the project.

Comment: why do i feel like this question belongs in some other place

Comment: @MCMXCII Thanks! Yes, I think I will do that. Positioning with margins alone seems abit hacky to me, but with floats / clears it seems more human.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ksav If you read to the end of the post, you would know. `So I was just looking for general advice -- how does the majority do it? What is best practice? There are apparently hundreds of ways to do it and I've looked through many guides and tutorials but I just don't get CSS positioning.`

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based or requires discussion** and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @JosephA. I know that docs are sometimes boring, but have a read of these:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I would say as a general rule of thumb, you should only ever use absolute positioning when you need something to overlap something else, eg modals, galleries, navs, etc.  As for using `br`s, that's what padding and margin is for - I would only use `br`s for a break in a sentence or a break between sections - not for styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four most commonly used position values are `initial, relative, absolute and fixed.`

The `fixed` value is used to position an element at a fixed position on the main screen.

The values `absolute and relative` are used to put an element in a fixed position relative to a parent. You need to define the element as `absolute` and his parent as `relative`.

Then you can do something like this:

```
<style>
    body{
        position:relative;
    }
    #copyright{
        position:absolute;
        top:5%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1> Welcome to my website. </h1>
    <p id="copyright"> Copyright 2016 </p>
</body>
```

[For more information see w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: All the answers are quite good - but this one is "accepted" because it provides an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well thats true if you take `position: absolute;` your page will never be resizable. If ouy make it with margin it's fine. It's much better than the `<br>` tag. If you have three 's on one row you can mak float: left; on each `<div>`. It will fit perfectly. If you zoom out then the fourth `<div>` on the new row will maybe come up or if you oom in there may be only two div's on a row.

tl;dr
Use `float: left;` for responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever way you want to choose, the problem is that it should render well on most devices using frameworks like [Material Design](https://material.google.com) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) will help you achieve that, but I generally go with margins and borders since div's are the building block of most professional websites.

Answer (score 0):

The `positon:absolute;`mean that the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

I am agree with @Blue said it's okay to use margin than `<br>`. You can use `float:` for responsive design.

Comment: I know what `position: absolute` is, and a definition was not exactly what I was looking for. However the `float` advice is pretty helpful: thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the good practice is to use margings for blocks positioning. But when we have some spesial cases - some kinds of elements on page wich out of stream it is necessary to use absolute positioning. But I try to avoid it if it's possible in my work